# C#: How is this performing faster with multiple functions, than inline code?

Tags: c#, performance, delegates

### Story

So, I wanted to create a small game for cross platform, but then I ended up in devices that don't support JIT, such as the IPhone, Windows mobile and Xbox One (game side, not application side).

Since the game had to generate some "basic" code out of text files with scripts in them, like formulas, assignments, call functions, modify/store values in a dictionary per object (sort of like a hybrid interactive fiction game), it wasn't really possible to do with AOT compilation.

After some thinking, I came up with a way around it, store collection of functions and what not, to "emulate" normal code. if this way was alot slower than twice as the compiled code, then I would consider dropping devices that couldn't run JIT compiled code.

I was expecting the compiled code in visual studio to be the fasted, and the Linq.Expressions to be about max 10% slower.

The hack of storing the functions and calling them for each and almost everything, I was expecting to be quite alot slower than compiled code, but..
**Too my surprise**, it is faster???

**Note:**
This project is primarily about learning and personal interests in my free time.
The end product is just a bonus, being able to sell or make it open source.

### Testing

Here is a test example of what I'm doing, and "trying" to model how the code would be used, where there are multiple "scripts" that have different functions and parameters, that operate on the TestObject.
**Interesting parts of the code are:**

- The constructor of the classes that derive from PerfTest.
- The Perform(TestObject obj) functions that they override.

This was compiled with Visual Studio 2017
.Net Framework 4.7.2
In release mode.
Optimizations turned on.
Platform target = x86 (haven't tested on ARM yet)
Tested the program with visual studio, and standalone, didn't make any noticeable difference in performance.

### Console Test Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new PerformanceTest();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done, press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class TestObject
    {
        public Dictionary<string, float> data = new Dictionary<string, float>();
        public TestObject(Random rnd)
        {
            data.Add("A", (float)rnd.NextDouble());
            data.Add("B", (float)rnd.NextDouble());
            data.Add("C", (float)rnd.NextDouble());
            data.Add("D", (float)rnd.NextDouble() + 1.0f);
            data.Add("E", (float)rnd.NextDouble());
            data.Add("F", (float)rnd.NextDouble() + 1.0f);
        }
    }
    class PerformanceTest
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        public PerformanceTest()
        {
            var rnd = new Random(1);
            int testSize = 5000000;
            int testTimes = 5;
            Console.WriteLine($"Creating {testSize} objects to test performance with");

            timer.Start();
            var data = new TestObject[testSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                data[i] = new TestObject(rnd);
            Console.WriteLine($"Created objects in {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds");

            int handlers = 1000;

            Console.WriteLine($"Creating {handlers} handlers per type");
            var tests = new PerfTest[3][];
            tests[0] = new PerfTest[handlers];
            tests[1] = new PerfTest[handlers];
            tests[2] = new PerfTest[handlers];

            for (int i = 0; i < tests[0].Length; i++)
                tests[0][i] = new TestNormal();
            for (int i = 0; i < tests[1].Length; i++)
                tests[1][i] = new TestExpression();
            for (int i = 0; i < tests[2].Length; i++)
                tests[2][i] = new TestOther();

            Console.WriteLine($"Handlers created");
            Console.WriteLine($"Warming up all handlers");

            for (int t = 0; t < tests.Length; t++)
                for (int i = 0; i < tests[t].Length; i++)
                    tests[t][i].Perform(data[0]);

            Console.WriteLine($"Testing data {testTimes} times with handlers of each type");
            for (int i = 0; i < testTimes; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int t = 0; t < tests.Length; t++)
                    Loop(tests[t], data);
            }

            timer.Stop();
        }

        void Loop(PerfTest[] test, TestObject[] data)
        {
            var rnd = new Random(1);
            var start = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            double sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                sum += test[rnd.Next(test.Length)].Perform(data[i]);

            var stop = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var elapsed = stop - start;

            Console.WriteLine($"{test[0].Name}".PadRight(25) + $"{elapsed} milliseconds".PadRight(20) + $"sum = { sum}");
        }
    }
    abstract class PerfTest
    {
        public string Name;
        public abstract float Perform(TestObject obj);
    }
    class TestNormal : PerfTest
    {
        public TestNormal()
        {
            Name = "\"Normal\"";
        }
        public override float Perform(TestObject obj) => obj.data["A"] * obj.data["B"] + obj.data["C"] / obj.data["D"] + obj.data["E"] / (obj.data["E"] + obj.data["F"]);
    }
    class TestExpression : PerfTest
    {
        Func<TestObject, float> compiledExpression;
        public TestExpression()
        {
            Name = "Compiled Expression";
            var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TestObject));
            var body = Expression.Add(Expression.Multiply(indexer(par, "A"), indexer(par, "B")), Expression.Add(Expression.Divide(indexer(par, "C"), indexer(par, "D")), Expression.Divide(indexer(par, "E"), Expression.Add(indexer(par, "E"), indexer(par, "F")))));

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TestObject, float>>(body, par);
            compiledExpression = lambda.Compile();
        }
        static Expression indexer(Expression parameter, string index)
        {
            var property = Expression.Field(parameter, typeof(TestObject).GetField("data"));
            return Expression.MakeIndex(property, typeof(Dictionary<string, float>).GetProperty("Item"), new[] { Expression.Constant(index) });
        }

        public override float Perform(TestObject obj) => compiledExpression(obj);
    }
    class TestOther : PerfTest
    {
        Func<TestObject, float>[] parameters;
        Func<float, float, float, float, float, float, float> func;
        public TestOther()
        {
            Name = "other";
            Func<float, float, float, float, float, float, float> func = (a, b, c, d, e, f) => a * b + c / d + e / (e + f);
            this.func = func; // this delegate will come from a collection of functions, depending on type

            parameters = new Func<TestObject, float>[]
            {
                (o) => o.data["A"],
                (o) => o.data["B"],
                (o) => o.data["C"],
                (o) => o.data["D"],
                (o) => o.data["E"],
                (o) => o.data["F"],
            };
        }
        float call(TestObject obj, Func<float, float, float, float, float, float, float> myfunc, Func<TestObject, float>[] parameters)
        {
            return myfunc(parameters[0](obj), parameters[1](obj), parameters[2](obj), parameters[3](obj), parameters[4](obj), parameters[5](obj));
        }
        public override float Perform(TestObject obj) => call(obj, func, parameters);
    }
}
```

### Output result of this Console test:

```
Creating 5000000 objects to test performance with
Created objects in 7489 milliseconds
Creating 1000 handlers per type
Handlers created
Warming up all handlers
Testing data 5 times with handlers of each type

"Normal"                 811 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047
Compiled Expression      1371 milliseconds   sum = 4174863.85436047
other                    746 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047

"Normal"                 812 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047
Compiled Expression      1379 milliseconds   sum = 4174863.85436047
other                    747 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047

"Normal"                 812 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047
Compiled Expression      1373 milliseconds   sum = 4174863.85436047
other                    747 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047

"Normal"                 812 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047
Compiled Expression      1373 milliseconds   sum = 4174863.85436047
other                    747 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047

"Normal"                 812 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047
Compiled Expression      1375 milliseconds   sum = 4174863.85436047
other                    746 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85436047

Done, press enter to exit
```

### Question

- Why is the class TestOther's Perform function faster than both
  TestNormal and TestExpression?
- And I expected the TestExpression to be closer to the TestNormal, why is it so far off?

Comment: Test expression compiles expression over and over again.

Comment: @just-my-name yes, for each handler created of type TestExpression, the delegate is stored, and then reused in the Perform function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt put the code into a profiler. I have looked at it and found that the main difference between the two fast ones and the slow compiled Expression was the dictionary lookup performance.

The Expression version needs more than twice as much CPU in Dictionary FindEntry compared to the others.

```
Stack                                                                           Weight (in view) (ms)
GameTest.exe!Test.PerformanceTest::Loop                                         15,243.896600
  |- Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly!dynamicClass::lambda_method      6,038.952700
  |- GameTest.exe!Test.TestNormal::Perform                                       3,724.253300
  |- GameTest.exe!Test.TestOther::call                                           3,493.239800
```

Then I did check the generated assembly code. It did look nearly identical and cannot explain the vast margin the expression version looses. 
I did also break into Windbg if different things were passed to the Dictionary[x] call but all did look normal.

To sum it up all of your versions do essentially the same amount of work (minus the double E lookup of the dictionary version but that plays no role for our Factor two) but the Expression version needs twice as much CPU. That is really a mystery.

Your benchmark code calls on each run a random test class instance. I have replaced that random walk by taking always the first instance instead of that random one:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        //  sum += test[rnd.Next(test.Length)].Perform(data[i]);
        sum += test[0].Perform(data[i]);
```

and now I get much better values:

```
Compiled Expression      740 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85440933
"Normal"                 743 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85430179
other                    714 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85430179
```

The problem with your code was/is that due to the many indirections you did get one indirection too far and the branch predictor of the CPU was no longer able to predict the next call target of the compiled expression which involves two hops. When I use the random walk then I get back the "bad" performance:

```
Compiled Expression      1359 milliseconds   sum = 4174863.85440933
"Normal"                 775 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85430179
other                    771 milliseconds    sum = 4174863.85430179
```

The observed bad behavior is highly CPU dependant and related to the CPU code and data cache size. I do not have VTune at hand to back that up with numbers but this once again shows that todays CPUs are tricky beasts.

I did run my code on a Core(TM) i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz.

Dictionaries are known to be very bad for cache predictors because they tend to wildly jump around in memory where no pattern can be found. The many dictionary calls seem to confuse the predictor already quite a bit and the additional randomnes of the used test instance and the more complex dispatch of the compiled expression was too much for the CPU to predict the memory access pattern and prefetch parts of it to L1/2 caches. In effect you were not testing the call performance but how good the CPU caching strategies were performing.

You should refactor your test code to use a simpler call pattern and perhaps use Benchmark.NET to factor these things out. That gives results which are in line with your expectations:

```
         Method |    N |     Mean |
--------------- |----- |---------:|
     TestNormal | 1000 | 3.175 us |
 TestExpression | 1000 | 3.480 us |
      TestOther | 1000 | 4.325 us |
```

The direct call is fastest, next comes the expression and last the delegate approach. But that was a micro benchmark. Your actual performance numbers can be different as you have found at the beginning and even counter intuitive.

Comment: The random part has the same seed for all the tests, so they are to say, equally updated in this test.  
How the "TestObject", will actually be updated, will be from queued up events from the game engine (physics, damage, user actions etc.), with either an id, or a reference to the object. This will then be updated in the next frame, or on background threads.  
  
Thank you for taking the time to go into such details, much appreciated.  
Also, I have the same processor as you. :)  
Selecting this as the answer, since you have answered both questions, and went into details.

Answer (score 1):

Your "normal" implementation

```
public override float Perform(TestObject obj)
{
    return obj.data["A"] * obj.data["B"] 
         + obj.data["C"] / obj.data["D"]
         + obj.data["E"] / (obj.data["E"] + obj.data["F"]);
}
```

is a bit inefficient. It calls `obj.data["E"]` twice, while the "other" implementation calls it only once. It you alter the code a bit

```
public override float Perform(TestObject obj)
{
    var e = obj.data["E"];
    return obj.data["A"] * obj.data["B"] 
         + obj.data["C"] / obj.data["D"] 
         + e / (e + obj.data["F"]);
}
```

it would perform as expected, slightly faster than the "other".

Comment: Nice catch, didn't see that.